# PHP Carbon get toDay date by formatting date

Tags: php, php-carbon

Simply I can format PHP date such as:

```
$current_date_time = new DateTime("now");
$user_current_date = $current_date_time->format("Y-m-d");
```

to get toDay date. how to do this action by using `Carbon` without time in date?

```
$now = Carbon::now();
echo $now;    // 2015-11-11 12:38:36
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The [documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting) is a good place to find this sort of thing. There are plenty of examples how to do it

```
$dt = Carbon::now()

var_dump($dt->toDateTimeString() == $dt);          // bool(true) => uses     __toString()
echo $dt->toDateString();                          // 1975-12-25
echo $dt->toFormattedDateString();                 // Dec 25, 1975
echo $dt->toTimeString();                          // 14:15:16
echo $dt->toDateTimeString();                      // 1975-12-25 14:15:16
echo $dt->toDayDateTimeString();                   // Thu, Dec 25, 1975 2:15 PM

// ... of course format() is still available
echo $dt->format('l jS \\of F Y h:i:s A');         // Thursday 25th of December 1975 02:15:16 PM
```

Answer (score 24):

You can add the static method `today()` at the end of the Carbon Object:

```
$today = Carbon::today()->toDateString();
```

Then `->toDateString()` to convert the carbon object to a date string.

This will take the Carbon Object of: `date: 2023-01-27 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00),` and modify it to a string `2023-01-27` without time stamp.

Answer (score 9):

You can format the output like this:
`Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');`